# Bin zc.buildout

Tags: python, mnist, buildout

```
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
    recipe being used:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/david/xbob.db.nist_sre12-1.1.1/eggs/zc.buildout-2.12.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 2128, in main
        getattr(buildout, command)(args)
      File "/home/david/xbob.db.nist_sre12-1.1.1/eggs/zc.buildout-2.12.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 798, in install
        installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
      File "/home/david/xbob.db.nist_sre12-1.1.1/eggs/zc.buildout-2.12.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1558, in _call
        return f()
      File "/home/david/xbob.db.nist_sre12-1.1.1/eggs/xbob.buildout-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/xbob/buildout/scripts.py", line 244, in install
        self.coverage.install_on_wrapped_env() + \
      File "/home/david/xbob.db.nist_sre12-1.1.1/eggs/xbob.buildout-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/xbob/buildout/python.py", line 83, in install_on_wrapped_env
        'paths': os.pathsep.join(tools.get_pythonpath(ws, self.buildout['buildout'], self.prefixes)),
      File "/home/david/xbob.db.nist_sre12-1.1.1/eggs/xbob.buildout-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/xbob/buildout/tools.py", line 242, in get_pythonpath
        prepend_path(zc.buildout.easy_install.setuptools_loc, paths)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setuptools_loc'
```

Trying to install buildout and its returning this error what could be the issue zc.buildout-2.12.2-py2.7.egg.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the xbob.buildout extension (https://pypi.org/project/xbob.buildout/), which does some modification to the path, apparently. For that it uses the `setuptools_loc` attribute in `zc.buildout.easy_install`, which apparently doesn't exist anymore.

The line in question was [removed in January 2017](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/commit/e129e187c1cde18b80e4d1d70c4751dfd55dc071), the line was part of the code that dealt with the old setuptools/distribute difference. It wasn't needed anymore.

So you should see if xbob.buildout can be adjusted (last release is from 2015). Or you could try to pick an old buildout (including an old setuptools).